# Spring Kafka multiple consumer for single topic consume different messages

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

In my Spring Boot Kafka application, I have the following consumer configuration:

```
@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, Post> postConsumerFactory(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties(), new StringDeserializer(), new JsonDeserializer<>(Post.class));
}

@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Post> postKafkaListenerContainerFactory(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {

    kafkaProperties.getProperties().put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, kafkaConsumerMaxPollIntervalMs);
    kafkaProperties.getProperties().put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, kafkaConsumerMaxPollRecords);

    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Post> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
    factory.setConsumerFactory(postConsumerFactory(kafkaProperties));

    return factory;
}
```

and the consumer:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.topic.post.send}", containerFactory = "postKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
public void sendPost(ConsumerRecord<String, Post> consumerRecord, Acknowledgment ack) {

    // do some logic

    ack.acknowledge();
}
```

If I understood correctly, right now I have one the single instance of my consumer.  I'd like to increase numbers of the post consumers, let's say to have 5 consumers that will consume different(not the same) messages from `${kafka.topic.post.send}` in order to speed up message consumption.

Is it as simple as add `factory.setConcurrency(5);` to my `postKafkaListenerContainerFactory()`, for example:

```
@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Post> postKafkaListenerContainerFactory(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {

    kafkaProperties.getProperties().put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, kafkaConsumerMaxPollIntervalMs);
    kafkaProperties.getProperties().put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, kafkaConsumerMaxPollRecords);

    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Post> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
    factory.setConsumerFactory(postConsumerFactory(kafkaProperties));
    factory.setConcurrency(5);

    return factory;
}
```

or do I need to do some extra work in order to achieve it?

Comment: you need multiple `group.id` so the messages are distributed among the various consumers in the same group for the same topic. you can have 1 micro service to do the process and run multiple instance of that with different group.id

Comment: alternatively you can define multiple listeners with different group.id in the same app ie: first `@KafkaListener(id = "listCRs", topics = "myTopic", containerFactory = "batchFactory")` second `@KafkaListener(id = "listCRsAck", topics = "myTopic", containerFactory = "batchFactory")`

Comment: @Paizo thanks, so I need to clone my `sendPost` method to number = desired listeners number with different ids and that's it?

Comment: also, why do we have `factory.setConcurrency(5);` method ? What is the purpose of this method?

Comment: my bad I was not aware of it; in addition of the 2 ways I mentioned the concurrency should do the trick as well see https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/htmlsingle/ `4.1.3 Receiving Messages`: `If, say, 6 TopicPartition s are provided and the concurrency is 3; each container will get 2 partitions`

Comment: I have the single Kafka instance on one node. How to know what number of topic partitions are provided and what is the container in this configuration?

Comment: partitions are dynamic, every time a new consumer with different group join/left kafka starts a rebalance to adjust the partitions numbers and distribute the records; you can check with `$ bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic my-topic`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not how Apache Kafka works. An idea there is always process records in the same partition in a single thread. That `factory.setConcurrency(5);` is definitely around how many partitions you have in a topic. So, if you have only one, this property doesn't bring any value. If you have 10 partitions in the topic, then Spring Kafka spawns 5 threads and each of them is going to handle 2 partition.

I would say this is pretty clear in the [Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.1.8.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#_concurrentmessagelistenercontainer):

> If, say, 6 TopicPartition s are provided and the concurrency is 3; each container will get 2 partitions. For 5 TopicPartition s, 2 containers will get 2 partitions and the third will get 1. If the concurrency is greater than the number of TopicPartitions, the concurrency will be adjusted down such that each container will get one partition.

So, if you would like to have such a concurrency you describe, you indeed have to create 5 partitions in your topic. And only after that you will be able to process records in the same topic in parallel.

Comment: If I have one topic and a group of consumers listening to this topic (say 10 of them), does it mean that 10 messages coming to this topic will be processed in parallel?

Comment: If all those messages are distributed between 10 partitions, then yes: it parallel. Records from the same partition are processed sequentially. Please, read Kafka docs to understand the architecture

Comment: thanks for the answer. I have gone through the doc, but have a quick question for my understanding. My understanding is that, If I put messsages into a topic without mentioning the partition, then all the message goes to same default partition. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: No, that’s not: by default records are distributed evenly